# How to make list in TextBox clickable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing a phone book in C#, when I click on "affichez tout vos contacts" (print all your contacts), it's print a list of contact in the textbox:

[image]

I'd like when I click on "Remi"'s line for example it's open a form, and in this form I get remi's data with costructeur, but I dont know how to get remi's data.

I suppose its Something like this?

```
private void TBnumero_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Form ModifierEtSupprimer = new Form(Name, Number);ModifierEtSupprimer.Show();
}
```

But I dont know how to get Name and Number.

Comment: Is this a WinForms or WPF application?

Comment: I would say a textbox is not really suitable for this, a listbox would be better, and you could override the style to make it look more like your screenshot.

Comment: @JayBuckman The icon in the screenshot looks like winforms.

Comment: its a IHM Windows form, but i have a webservice, its running my functions

Comment: I would change the control from Textbox to a DatagridView or ListBox. That way you can tell in which row you are and bring the corresponding Name - phone pair

Comment: i' watched list box in google, i juste have to do listbox1.add item; and when the list box is full i use listbox.selected item ?

Comment: Maybe a LIstView is a better choice. If you also have or want to use images (maybe just to have a visual representation of the type of contact, etc.). It also allow you to organize the data in 4 different ways with a single command. Easier to customize, in case you want to owner-draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ListBox as your control. 1st Add items to listbox:

```
ListBox phoneBook = new ListBox();
pnoheBook.Items.Add("Remi 741256");
pnoheBook.Items.Add("Khahal 164235");
pnoheBook.Items.Add("thegod 5578");
....
```

Then register the selection Change Event and pass the selection to new Form:

```
private void pnoheBook_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnoheBook.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
       return;// no selection we exit.
    }         
    var selection = pnoheBook.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(' ');
    Form ModifierEtSupprimer = new Form(selection[0], selection[1]);
    ModifierEtSupprimer.Show();
}
```

Comment: re, thanks for answer, i have a bug  :System.NullReferenceException : 'La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.' in the line :  var selection = pnoheBook.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(' ');

Comment: @martingenereux Yes it must be the case where there is no selection on listbox. I willl edit

Comment: hmm it's weird, still doesnt work, i tried with Selected item, i did : Form ModifierEtSupprimer = new formmodifiersupprimer(LBaffiche.SelectedItem.ToString()); and it's give me the datas but when i try to use '.split(' ')' its not working and its give me only the first letter, for exemple if i split 'Remi 741256, Remi[0] = R and Remi[1] = e'

Comment: sorry i dont understand how to indent in comment's section